# VNC Server installed from SSH only shows grey screen

Tags: xorg, vnc

I am attempting to remote access my machine, and only have SSH available to me right now. I have the VNC Viewer installed on my workstation, and installed a VNC Server on my ElementaryOS computer using `apt install tightvncserver`. I started it (as a regular user), but I only see a grey screen.

My ~/.vnc/xstartup file looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work


export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session 'gnome-session --session=pantheon'
```

When I run `vncserver`, and connect to the display it creates, I only see a grey screen. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the solution listed in: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/18812/9699

Comment: @DavidHewitt After fighting with it some more, that solution helped. Thank you!